# Can nth root of 2 be a rational number for any natural number n > 1?

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

We know square and cube root of 2 are irrational numbers, but is it possible for any a rational number to be multiplied by itself finite times and it results in 2.

Comment: No, with the same proof used for proving that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

Comment: @Jean Marie so this is true for any prime number??

Comment: Exactly, due to unicity of primary factor decomposition.

Comment: thnx @Jean Marie for help

Comment: Um, does $1$ count as a natural number? (Maybe edit the title to say $n>1$.)

Comment: thnx @timtfj, did it